# Sparse Matrix with linked lists

Tags: c, list, matrix, linked-list, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to create a sparse matrix in C using linked lists. My professor gave the `file.h` structs, a list of the functions and what they should do and told us to "work with it".
To resume everything, my code does not work, it stops working when I try to insert an element (calling `ins_elem()`) and returning weird number when calling `soma_elem_coluna()` and `soma_elem_linha()`.

I've put the whole code below but the issue is really within the functions specified above (and `soma_const()` as I can't test it without inserting an element).

The logic I used is to create a matrix as in the image below (with numbers instead of characters)
[[image: 1]]

Don't mind the weird typing, some words are in Portuguese.

(C = column and L = row)

this is my `file.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LINES 4
#define COLUM 4

typedef struct Node{
    int Val, L, C;
    struct Node *down, *right;
}Node;

typedef struct{
    Node *L[LINES], *C[COLUM];
}matriz;

void cria_matriz(matriz* m);                       // creates matrix
void ins_elem(matriz* m, int e, int l, int c);     // insert element e into lxc 
void soma_const(matriz* m, int e, int l, int c);   // add value e to existing lxc
int soma_elem_linha(matriz *m, int l);             // sums all the values in row l
int soma_elem_coluna(matriz *m, int c);            // sums all the values in column c
void imp(matriz *m);                               // prints the matrix
```

my `file.c`

```
#include "file.h"

void cria_matriz(matriz* m) 
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<LINES;i++) //initializes headrows
    {
        m->L[i]->down = NULL;
        m->L[i]->right = NULL;
        m->L[i]->C = -1;
        m->L[i]->L = -1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<COLUM;i++) //initializes headcolumns
    {
        m->C[i]->down = NULL;
        m->C[i]->right = NULL;
        m->C[i]->C = -1;
        m->C[i]->L = -1;
    }
}

void ins_elem(matriz *m, int e, int l, int c)
{
    Node* auxLine; // move through row
    Node* auxCol; // move through column
    auxLine = &m->L[l];
    auxCol = &m->C[c];
    while(auxLine->right != NULL && auxLine->right->C < c) //find correct pos in row
    {
        auxLine = auxLine->right;
    }
    while(auxCol->down != NULL && auxCol->down->L < c) //find correct pos in column (error happens here)
    {
        auxCol = auxCol->down;
    }
    Node* novo = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    novo->Val = e;
    novo->C = c;
    novo->L = l;
    novo->down = auxCol->down;
    auxCol->down = novo;
    novo->right = auxLine->right;
    auxLine->right = novo;
}

void soma_const(matriz *m, int e, int l, int c)
{
    Node* aux = &m->C[c];
    while(aux->down != NULL && aux->L < l)
        aux = aux->down;
    aux->Val+=e;
}

int soma_elem_coluna(matriz *m, int c)
{
    int sum = 0;
    Node* aux = &m->C[c];
    if(aux->down == NULL)
        return 0;
    while(aux->down != NULL)
    {
        aux = aux->down;
        sum += aux->Val;
    }
    return sum;
}

int soma_elem_linha(matriz *m, int l)
{
    int sum = 0;
    Node* aux = &m->L[l];
    if(aux->right == NULL)
        return 0;
    while(aux->right != NULL)
    {
        aux = aux->right;
        sum += aux->Val;
    }
    return sum;
}

void imp(matriz *m)
{
    Node* aux;
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<LINES;i++)
    {
        aux = &m->L[i];
        for(j=0;j<COLUM;j++)
        {
            if(aux->C == j)
            {
                printf("%d ",aux->Val);
                aux = aux->right;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("0 ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

my `main.c`:

```
#include "file.h"

int main()
{
    struct matriz* M = (matriz*)malloc(sizeof(matriz));
    int i,e,c,l,result;
    char str[20];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) // this is temporary and another issue, how I make a while that 
    {                 // only stops when user (a bot actually) presses enter?
        scanf(" %s",str);

        if(!strcmp(str,"cria_matriz"))
        {
            cria_matriz(M);
        }
        else if(!strcmp(str,"ins_elem"))
        {
            scanf("%d %d %d",&e,&l,&c);
            ins_elem(M,e,l,c);
        }
        else if(!strcmp(str,"soma_const"))
        {
            scanf("%d %d %d",&e,&l,&c);
            soma_const(M,e,l,c);
        }
        else if(!strcmp(str,"soma_elem_linha"))
        {
            scanf("%d",&l);
            result = soma_elem_linha(M,l);
            printf("%d\n",result);
        }
        else if(!strcmp(str,"soma_elem_coluna"))
        {
            scanf("%d",&c);
            result = soma_elem_coluna(M,c);
            printf("%d\n",result);
        }
        else if(!strcmp(str,"imp"))
        {
            imp(M);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No one? It's already been 3 hours and I still can't fix it...

Comment: It's so unclear what goes wrong with your code. You should learn how to use the debugger. You will learn 10x faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your files didn't compile without warnings as there were lots of pointer and other problems with the code.  I've worked over your code to clean up the warnings but I'm not in a position to test the logic -- you'll have to do that:

**file.c**

```
#include "file.h"

void cria_matriz(matriz *m) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LINES; i++) // initializes headrows
    {
        m->L[i] = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        m->L[i]->down = NULL;
        m->L[i]->right = NULL;
        m->L[i]->C = -1;
        m->L[i]->L = -1;
        m->L[i]->Val = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < COLUM; i++) // initializes headcolumns
    {
        m->C[i] = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        m->C[i]->down = NULL;
        m->C[i]->right = NULL;
        m->C[i]->C = -1;
        m->C[i]->L = -1;
        m->C[i]->Val = 0;
    }
}

void ins_elem(matriz *m, int e, int l, int c)
{
    Node *auxLine = m->L[l]; // move through row
    Node *auxCol = m->C[c]; // move through column

    while (auxLine->right != NULL && auxLine->right->C < c) // find correct pos in row
    {
        auxLine = auxLine->right;
    }

    while (auxCol->down != NULL && auxCol->down->L < c) // find correct pos in column (error happens here)
    {
        auxCol = auxCol->down;
    }

    Node *novo = malloc(sizeof(*novo));
    novo->Val = e;
    novo->C = c;
    novo->L = l;
    novo->down = auxCol->down;

    auxCol->down = novo;
    novo->right = auxLine->right;
    auxLine->right = novo;
}

void soma_const(matriz *m, int e, int l, int c)
{
    Node *aux = m->C[c];

    while (aux->down != NULL && aux->L < l)
    {
        aux = aux->down;
    }

    aux->Val += e;
}

int soma_elem_coluna(matriz *m, int c)
{
    Node *aux = m->C[c];

    if (aux->down == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    int sum = 0;

    while (aux->down != NULL)
    {
        aux = aux->down;
        sum += aux->Val;
    }

    return sum;
}

int soma_elem_linha(matriz *m, int l)
{
    Node *aux = m->L[l];

    if (aux->right == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    int sum = 0;

    while (aux->right != NULL)
    {
        aux = aux->right;
        sum += aux->Val;
    }

    return sum;
}

void imp(matriz *m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LINES; i++)
    {
        Node *aux = m->L[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < COLUM; j++)
        {
            if (aux->C == j)
            {
                printf("%d ", aux->Val);
                aux = aux->right;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("0 ");
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "file.h"

int main()
{
    matriz *M = malloc(sizeof(*M));
    int e, c, l;
    char str[32];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // this is temporary and another issue, how I make a while that 
    {               // only stops when user (a bot actually) presses enter?
        (void) scanf(" %s", str);

        if (strcmp(str, "cria_matriz") == 0)
        {
            cria_matriz(M);
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "ins_elem") == 0)
        {   
            scanf("%d %d %d", &e, &l, &c);
            ins_elem(M, e, l, c);
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "soma_const") == 0)
        {
            (void) scanf("%d %d %d", &e, &l, &c);
            soma_const(M, e, l, c);
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "soma_elem_linha") == 0)
        {
            (void) scanf("%d", &l);
            int result = soma_elem_linha(M, l);
            printf("%d\n", result);
        }
        else if (strcmp(str, "soma_elem_coluna") == 0)
        {
            scanf("%d", &c);
            int result = soma_elem_coluna(M, c);
            printf("%d\n", result);
        }
        else if (strcmp(str,"imp") == 0)
        {
            imp(M);
        }
    }

    free(M);

    return 0;
}
```

The biggest issue was that you kept making pointers to things that were already pointers.  Also, you initialized data that you hadn't actually allocated.  You didn't initialize some data that you subsequently added onto.  Finally, `strcmp()` isn't a boolean, don't use it as one.